# Function that takes a function with multiple arguments and returns a function with a single tuple argument

Tags: python, naming

Is there a standard name for the higher-order function that takes a function with multiple arguments and returns a function with a single tuple argument:

```
def what_am_i(f):
    def f1(tup):
        f(*tup)
    return f1
```

This is not the same as `uncurry` in most programming languages, which I usually see defined as:

```
def uncurry(f):
    def f1(a, b):
        return f(a)(b)
    return f1
```

Comment: This is similar to "variable length argument lists" in several languages.

Answer (score 1):

## `apply()`

In JavaScript, this is called [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```js
'use strict'

function test(a, b, c) {
  // context
  console.log(this)
  // arguments
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
  console.log(c)
}

// first parameter is the context
test.apply('this', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Unfortunately, the first argument tends to clutter the function call in a lot of cases where the `this` is unimportant, and therefore you would pass a value like `null` or `undefined`, but in some edge cases it can be very useful.

In cases where you just want to specify the array, you could implement a wrapper function that's equivalent to your example like so:

```js
function test(a, b, c) {
  // arguments
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
  console.log(c)
}

// what am I? I am `apply()`
function apply(f) {
  return function (tup) {
    return f.apply(this, tup)
  }
}

var applied = apply(test)

applied(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

## `spread()`

Another argument you could make is to call it `spread()`, because the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) does the same thing:

```js
function test(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
  console.log(c)
}

test(...['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

and you can implement a wrapper function that's very intuitive which looks like this:

```js
function test(a, b, c) {
  console.log(a)
  console.log(b)
  console.log(c)
}

// what am I? I am `spread()`
function spread(f) {
  return function (tup) {
    return f(...tup)
  }
}

var spreaded = spread(test)

spreaded(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: I think `apply` in other languages means to simply call the function with the supplied arguments without spreading, but `spread` (aka `splat`) I like.